# Deploy folder structure from Jenkins

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, deployment

I'm new to Jenkins. I've found the plugin [Deploy Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Deploy+Plugin) which allows automatic deployment of **war/ear** files. However, let's say I only have a folder structure in the lines of:

```
└── Web Application Folder
    ├── css
    │   └── *.css
    ├── js
    │   └── *.js
    └── index.html
```

How can I deploy such a folder structure to a Tomcat (8.5.6) server?

**EDIT**

So I found a solution - but it's not pretty nice. As shown below I needed to add a shell script in the **Build** phase to create a tmp folder and move all files into the folder. Then in the **Post-Build Actions** the folder is deployed with the **Artifact Deployer** plugin (this can only be done assuming I now the full path to tomcat webapps folder) and at last the tmp folder is deleted.

[Build Setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zBPpb.png)

There must be an easier and more robust way?